# I need help to display using date_time function twice i the same sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime

Please i need help in displaying the date like 4th july - 20th july, 2012 using the date_time() function. how do i do this?
below is what i thought might work, but it didin't.

```
$query_rssynod = "SELECT syID, session, year, theme, venue, 
                  DATE_FORMAT(startdate, enddate, '%d %b', '%d %b, %Y.') AS DATE 
                 FROM synod";
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(startdate), '%D %M'), ' - ', DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(enddate), '%D %M %Y'))
```

basically **[DATE_FORMAT( )](http://davidwalsh.name/format-date-mysql-date_format)** accepts the date to be formatted and the format of the date.

Comment: Nice, but this will end with garbage, if the event goes over a year change.

Comment: Tried it, but it did not work. I think i should have mentioned that both the startdate and enddate are different fields in the table with timestamp type. Does that help?

Comment: @AgbogidiMichael try it again, added `FROM_UNIXTIME()` function

Comment: @John Woo: thanks for your responce, but still could not get it output the date fields from the table. Its just blank.

Comment: @AgbogidiMichael can you add sample records so we can work on that?

Comment: @ John Woo: sory for the trouble and Thanks a lot for your help. I have records already in the database. other fields are showing but the date field is not outputting.

Comment: @ John: this was my initial code      mysql_select_db($database_connDioceseofife, $connDioceseofife);
$query_rssynod = "SELECT syID, session, year, theme, venue, DATE_FORMAT(startdate, '%d %b') AS STARTDATE, DATE_FORMAT(enddate, '%d %b, %Y.') AS ENDDATE FROM synod"; 
$query_limit_rssynod = sprintf("%s LIMIT %d, %d", $query_rssynod, $startRow_rssynod, $maxRows_rssynod);
$rssynod = mysql_query($query_limit_rssynod, $connDioceseofife) or die(mysql_error());
$row_rssynod = mysql_fetch_assoc($rssynod);

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
  syID, session, year, theme, venue,
  CONCAT(
    IF(
      YEAR(enddate)=YEAR(startdate),
      DATE_FORMAT(startdate, '%D %M'),
      DATE_FORMAT(startdate, '%D %M, %Y')
    ),
    ' - ',
    DATE_FORMAT(enddate, '%D %M, %Y')
  ) AS `DATE`
FROM synod
```

Comment: Tried it, but it did not work. I think i should have mentioned that both the startdate and enddate are different fields in the table with timestamp type. Does that help?

Comment: @AgbogidiMichael Please post the exact error message and the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE synod` !

Comment: @ Eugen: i am not getting any error. Its just that the field for date is blank. Other data are visible.

Comment: @ Eugen sorry. When i put it like below, it outputs no error but date field is blank. other fields are visible.
  mysql_select_db($database_connDioceseofife, $connDioceseofife);
$query_rssynod = "SELECT syID, session, year, theme, venue, DATE_FORMAT(startdate, '%d %b') AS STARTDATE, DATE_FORMAT(enddate, '%d %b, %Y.') AS ENDDATE FROM synod"; 
$query_limit_rssynod = sprintf("%s LIMIT %d, %d", $query_rssynod, $startRow_rssynod, $maxRows_rssynod);
$rssynod = mysql_query($query_limit_rssynod, $connDioceseofife) or die(mysql_error());
$row_rssynod = mysql_fetch_assoc($rssynod);

Comment: Still need the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE synod`

Comment: @ Eugen: CREATE TABLE `synod` (
  `syID` int(12) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `session` varchar(256) collate latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `year` varchar(4) collate latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `theme` varchar(256) collate latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `venue` varchar(256) collate latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `startdate` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `enddate` timestamp NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`syID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;

Comment: @ Eugen: INSERT INTO `synod` VALUES (1, 'First Session of the First Synod', '1991', 'CHRIST THE CENTRE', 'The Cathedral Church of St. Philip Ayetoro, Ile Ife', '1991-04-04 00:00:00', '1991-04-07 00:00:00');

Comment: I just entered the `CREATE TABLE`, the `INSERT` and my `SELECT` into an instance of MySQL 5.5.24 and got "4th April - 7th April, 1991" for the date. This rules out the SQL as the problem. Either you have an error in the code creating your SQL (You can check by echoing the SQL befire executing it) or in retrieveing the resul. The query is OK.

Answer (score 0):

You should print the dates in your required format as follows:

```
CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(startdate, "%d %b"), ' - ', DATE_FORMAT(enddate, "%d %b"), ', ', DATE_FORMAT(startdate, "%Y"));
```

Comment: Tried it, but it did not work. I think i should have mentioned that both the startdate and enddate are different fields in the table with timestamp type. Does that help?

Comment: I actually treated the columns as variables (that `@` should have been removed). Corrected the snippet.